# Unable to install MySQL on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, installation, rubygems

I'm having the exact issue as described in this question: [MYSQL Installation Troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354194/mysql-installation-troubles). Unfortunately none of the answers helped me (and it's closed).

I try to learn Ruby on Rails and don't get MySQL working (so it is programming related).

I typed: `rake db:create` and got:

```
!!!The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- mysql

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
HD-Auckland:shoutbox max$ gem install mysql
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
      /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/max/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/max/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/max/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

So as it told me I tried `sudo gem install mysql` and got:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/opt/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/local/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

I also tried this command `sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config` and got the same error!

What can I do? I only want to migrate my db to the MySQL server!

Thanks for help, Mexx

#### Update:

Thanks for all the great response! Yes, I am on Snow Leopard.
I downloaded mysql from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#macosx-dmg and installed it.
I then followed Hivelogic's guide for the mysql installation.

when I now type: `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`or `sudo gem istall mysql` or `sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql`

I will get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
fotoSuccessfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result

No definition for field_name

No definition for field_table

No definition for field_def

No definition for field_type

No definition for field_length

No definition for field_max_length

No definition for field_flags

No definition for field_decimals

No definition for time_inspect

No definition for time_to_s

No definition for time_get_year

No definition for time_get_month

No definition for time_get_day

No definition for time_get_hour

No definition for time_get_minute

No definition for time_get_second

No definition for time_get_neg

No definition for time_get_second_part

No definition for time_set_year

No definition for time_set_month

No definition for time_set_day

No definition for time_set_hour

No definition for time_set_minute

No definition for time_set_second

No definition for time_set_neg

No definition for time_set_second_part

No definition for time_equal

No definition for error_errno

No definition for error_sqlstate
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result

No definition for field_name

No definition for field_table

No definition for field_def

No definition for field_type

No definition for field_length

No definition for field_max_length

No definition for field_flags

No definition for field_decimals

No definition for time_inspect

No definition for time_to_s

No definition for time_get_year

No definition for time_get_month

No definition for time_get_day

No definition for time_get_hour

No definition for time_get_minute

No definition for time_get_second

No definition for time_get_neg

No definition for time_get_second_part

No definition for time_set_year

No definition for time_set_month

No definition for time_set_day

No definition for time_set_hour

No definition for time_set_minute

No definition for time_set_second

No definition for time_set_neg

No definition for time_set_second_part

No definition for time_equal

No definition for error_errno

No definition for error_sqlstate
```

And doing `rake db:create` will end up with:

```
(in /Users/max/rails/shoutbox)
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- mysql

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, how you have installed mysql, from the binaries of the mysql site, fink, ports, brew, etc. ?

Comment: sudo port install mysql5 +server rb-mysql

I think I did command but wasn't anymore sure when you asked so I did it again and it is downloading now :/ sorry guys - hope I didnt wast your time. will update here once it is finished.

Comment: doing the install via macports I get this error:

Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: lipo: can't open input file: /opt/local/lib/libz.dylib (No such file or directory)
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.

Comment: You can follow Hivelogic's guide for the mysql installation.
http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard

Answer (score 7):

for some reason (maybe because i'm using rubygems 1.3.7 or installing mysql-2.8.1)

```
sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

did not work for me so after taking a look at gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/extconf.rb i found out that the extconf.rb looks in the PATH for mysql_config so i tried

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
sudo gem install mysql
```

and did the job

Answer (score 1):

Are you on snow leopard? You have to execute the C dependencies compiles with x64 headers, try:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: You don't have to do that. I installed 64-bit MySQL on Snow Leopard from source using these instructions and it works fine: http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 1):

I have run into issues with the MySQL gem myself and these are the only 2 links I actually bookmarked, so one of should have actually worked for me. Thought I'd share.

1. http://wonko.com/post/how-to-install-the-mysqlruby-gem-on-mac-os-x-leopard
2. http://rapd.wordpress.com/2007/05/17/battle-against-ror-gem-install-mysql/

The second one is kind of old, so not sure if it still applies.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install the MySQL gem on OS X, you need to install the XCode developer tools that come on your installation disk. You can also download them from http://developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

I just end up with that problem using this command:

```
 sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -v 2.8.1 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Indeed I needed to install mysql gem version 2.8.1 on my mac OS X Leopard 10.5.8 running the mysql-5.6.2-m5-osx10.5-x86 from dmg file. I had the issue that it couldn't find libraries and I made some manipulations, then it couldn't install because of permissions. I found out that command, added the version I needed and changed architecture to the one corresponding to my mysql installation.

So if somenone still wants to install that version :) let's try ! But we are not a lot installing this probably, and less on Leopard!

Answer (score 0):

The correct gem to use is `mysql2`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved installing first the adapter:

```
gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
```

Then, install mysql2 gem using

```
sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```