# Rails, install gem mysql2 error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

```
username@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/RoR/rails_projects/twitter/config$ gem in
stall mysql2 > ~/Desktop/outputfile
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/mysql2-0.3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/mysql2-0.3.6/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

What is wrong with it? How should I fix this?
Thank you so much

Comment: Can you also show the `mkmf.log` file?

Comment: @ace Where is that? I tried,but not found it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I found another SO link for installing MySQL. Try following this first before trying homebrew.
[Unable to install MySQL on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014765/unable-to-install-mysql-on-mac-os-x)

Homebrew:

Using homebrew is an alternative solution to installing MySQL.
Actually I use homebrew for almost everything else.

This is the installation link with the docs.
 https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation

The basic commands / readme.
[Link](https://brew.sh/)

Once it is installed, you can just

```
brew install mysql
```

Here are some google search results (search is `brew install mysql`) that could guide you.
The SO link is if you are having root password issues.
http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2010/02/28/installing-mysql-on-snow-leopard-using-homebrew/
[brew install mysql on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os)

Answer (score -1):

Before the installation of mysql gem install following. this is for ubuntu ..

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: i was going to downvote like someone else but instead I added the osx tag for the original poster.  Seeing macbook in the middle of the code was a bit obscure.