# Error while install mysql gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Install log:

```
Using launchy (2.3.0) 
Using libv8 (3.11.8.17)  
Installing mysql2 (0.3.11)  
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. 

    /home/sanjay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby extconf.rb  
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes 
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes 
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no 
checking for main() in -lm... yes 
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no 
checking for main() in -lz... yes 
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no 
checking for main() in -lsocket... no 
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no 
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes 
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no 
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no 
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no 
*** extconf.rb failed *** 
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of 
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more 
details.  You may need configuration options. 

Provided configuration options: 
    --with-opt-dir 
    --without-opt-dir 
    --with-opt-include 
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include 
    --with-opt-lib 
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib 
    --with-make-prog 
    --without-make-prog 
    --srcdir=. 
    --curdir 
    --ruby=/home/sanjay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby 
    --with-mysql-config 
    --without-mysql-config 
    --with-mysql-dir 
    --without-mysql-dir 
    --with-mysql-include 
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include 
    --with-mysql-lib 
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib 
    --with-mysqlclientlib 
    --without-mysqlclientlib 
    --with-mlib 
    --without-mlib 
    --with-mysqlclientlib 
    --without-mysqlclientlib 
    --with-zlib 
    --without-zlib 
    --with-mysqlclientlib 
    --without-mysqlclientlib 
    --with-socketlib 
    --without-socketlib 
    --with-mysqlclientlib 
    --without-mysqlclientlib 
    --with-nsllib 
    --without-nsllib 
    --with-mysqlclientlib 
    --without-mysqlclientlib 
    --with-mygcclib 
    --without-mygcclib 
    --with-mysqlclientlib 
    --without-mysqlclientlib 

extconf failed, exit code 1 

Gem files will remain installed in /home/sanjay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems /mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection. 
Results logged to /home/sanjay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1 /mysql2-0.3.11/gem_make.out 

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue. 
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: As said in this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension) You should run `sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev` before trying to install mysql2 gem

Answer (score 4):

for ubuntu use this:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient16 ruby-dev

sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libmysqlclient16, how can I fix this?

Comment: You only need libmysqlclient-dev

Answer (score 2):

If on ubuntu debian system, Check for libmysql-ruby and libmysqlclient-dev library package.
It is a common problem while installing mysql2 gem on ubuntu/debian system. Follow this link of stackoverflow @ [Error installing mysql2: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension?lq=1)

And if on Mac system, which probably seems so by looking at error log in your question, follow this stackoverflow link for solution @ [Unable to install MySQL on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014765/unable-to-install-mysql-on-mac-os-x)